# Error message when opening Media Manager in SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, media-manager

I get the following message when I open SDL Media Manager from inside of Tridion 2011. Wondering what the cause could be:

```
The requested service, 'http://[client's name].sdlmedia.com/WebServices/MediaManager2011.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
```

Is this something I can fix on my end, or is my only recourse to contact SDL?

Comment: sorry for not providing an update sooner. It turns out that SDL had some certificate issues with Media Manager, and also a database issue. It took us about three days to resolve everything. Lesson Learned: if you've followed the instructions correctly, and it doesn't work, open a ticket with SDL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Was it running previously, or is this the first time you try to use it?

Typically it's certificates giving problems, so triple check that it's the correct ones that are configured, and access rights and trust are correct.

If you can't find an error in the client side certificates, contact SDL support - they can most likely see the error in the log files on the server, and if not they can enable WCF tracing.